# Array from query results php inside while

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this code, which is parcially working... I'm trying to do this:

```
Array
(
    [servicio_id 1] => Array
        (
            [peticion_id 1] => Array
                (...)
            [peticion_id 2] => Array
                (...)
            [peticion_id 3] => Array
                (...)
         )
    [servicio_id 2] => Array
        (
            [peticion_id 1] => Array
                (...)
            [peticion_id 2] => Array
                (...)
            [peticion_id 3] => Array
                (...)
         )
)
```

So each [servicio_id] has it's [peticion_id] with its own values... the problem is that my code actually set the same values inside every [peticion_id] array, increasing it's size as long as the loop is running... Any advice on how to clear and start again the [peticion_id] array once the [servicio_id] is finished?

Thank you in advice

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlQuery)) {
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 0) {
        $ok[]       =   round($row['valor'], 3);
        if($row['media_ok'] == null) {
            $medias_ok = array("0", "0", "0", "0");
        } else {
            $medias_ok = Umbrales::getValues($row['media_ok'], $row['media']);
        }   
        $max_ok[] = $medias_ok[1];
        $min_ok[] = $medias_ok[0];
    }
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 1) {
        $ko[]       =   round($row['valor'], 3);
        if($row['media_ok'] == null) {
            $medias_ko = array("0", "0", "0", "0");
        } else {
            $medias_ko = Umbrales::getValues($row['media_ok'], $row['media']);
        }   
        $max_ko[] = $medias_ko[2];
    }
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 2) {
        $rt[]       =   round($row['valor'], 3);
        if($row['media_ok'] == null) {
            $medias_rt = array("0", "0", "0", "0");
        } else {
            $medias_rt = Umbrales::getValues($row['media_ok'], $row['media']);
        }   
        $max_rt[] = $medias_rt[3];
    }
    $datos[$servicios[$row['servicio_id']]] = array(
    "OK" => $ok,
    "KO" => $ko,
    "RT" => $rt,
    "UMBRAL_MIN_OK" => $min_ok,
    "UMBRAL_MAX_OK" => $max_ok,
    "UMBRAL_MAX_KO" => $max_ko,
    "UMBRAL_MAX_RT" => $max_rt
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the array on each loop.
After you while it should read:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlQuery)) {

    $ok = array();
    $ko = array();
    $rt = array();
    $min_ok = array();
    $max_ok = array();
    $max_ko = array();
    $max_rt = array();

    if($row['peticion_id'] == 0) {
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it isn't working, i got this...             [OK] => Array
                (
                )

Comment: OK will only be set for peticion_id 0.

Comment: :S What I want is to clear the arrays for each servicio_id... so if servicio_id has changed, then clear the arrays... that's what I want